# Increasing number of items/records per page in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Amazon recently announced a new console for DynamoDB (Nov 2015) and I noticed that the number of items/records displayed per page has decreased from 100 to 50 per page, making it more difficult to quickly export to csv.

Can that be changed somewhere in the settings?

Comment: I tried asking the same question in the AWS Developer's Forum, but no luck so far. If there's a response, I'll post it here too.

Comment: According to the reply from AWS Developer's Forum, the number has been increased to 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2019, you can go to **Preferences** page, under DynamoDB, and choose 100, 200 or 300 on the **Items tab page size**

[image]